# Call data from my database to view ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks guys for collaborate. 
I have a project with ruby on rails
And i have an scaffold Dream. 
I have another scaffold called Microposts http://lapapaya.org/microposts
And im trying to show Microposts content in to my Dreams/show view. 
This is my Dreams/show code:

```
<br>
<br>
<p> Compártelo</p>
<%= social_share_button_tag("My Site") %>

<% if @dream.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Editar', edit_dream_path(@dream) %> |
<br>
<br>

<!-- 
<%= current_user.gioco_data %>
<%= current_user.track_event('Login') %>
-->

<!-- 
<p><strong><%= @dream.user.email if @dream.user %></strong></p>-->

<%= link_to 'Publicar un post', new_micropost_path, class: "btn btn-primary"  %> 
<%= @micropost = Micropost.all %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I defined this method in my dreams/controller:

```
 def micropost
    @micropost = Micropost.first
  end
```

But what i get is this: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/3746cd9b-d9b9-4c0b-abd1-5d8dbb782d5d/a0cafb5f9bd407ee331a8a876d923788
And i can't show my micropost content. 
I would like to understand the logic of the sistem of calling info from my database to the views.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly with micropost in the dream#view page ? Does each dream have many microposts ?

Comment: Yes, and i would like to print every micropost asociated with this dream.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<%= @micropost = Micropost.all %>
```

return a collection of microposts. You have to specify how to show each one. So, in your dreams_controller, add this line to your index method:

```
@microposts = Micropost.all
```

And in your view, replace that line with something like this:

```
<% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  <h1><%= micropost.title %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Please note that <%= %> means print the result of the the erb code in between. while <% %> will only execute it without printing anything to the html page.

Comment: Ok, yes, i suposed <%= @micropost = Micropost.all %> would return a collection of microposts, but it returns: #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Micropost:0x007fbe65d7d7e8> not the content

Comment: And this is what i get with @microposts.ead do undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That's how Ruby identify objects. Everything in Ruby is an object. If you run, "rails console" in the command line (after navigating to the project directory) and do Micropost.all.class it will tell you that it is ActiveRecord_Relation.

As for the second issue. You probably did not define @microposts in dreams_controller as I said or you have misspelled it. Anything that's not defined is an object of NilClass. Try this:
`<% Micropost.all.each do |micropost| %>
  <h1><%= micropost.title %></h1>
<% end %>`
You really need a Ruby on Rails tutorial. I recommend http://railsforzombies.org/

Comment: I don't know what values micropost have, If it doesn't have a title column or method, you will get an error: `undefined method 'title'`

Comment: Thanks! I have defined micropost in my dreams controller:             def micropost
    @micropost = Micropost.all
  end                    and completely agree, i'm just begining and i will love to understand the logic between my database information and the views.